# How can I get the URL of the website I'm on without reloading the page if I accidentally typed something in the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm on a website in Google Chrome, and go to copy the URL, but mistakenly hit `V` instead of `CTRL+V`, so now all I have in my address bar is a `V`. The page has information on it that I don't want to reload and/or resubmit.

How do I get the URL that was there?

Comment: click in the address bar(if focus isn't already there, though it seems your focus is already there so no need to click even), and hit ESC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

It only works if address bar is focused, and it probably is if you've just wanted to paste something. You can focus it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or clicking on it.

Comment: to focus on the address bar- ctrl-L or alt-d, or a click there.

Comment: also one would never need to "make sure" that address bar is focussed, unless one is blind. One can see if it is focussed or not.  Also if he just mistakenly hit V, then the address bar has focus, and he can see the address bar is focussed (unless he is blind). So he just has to hit ESC.

Comment: @barlop You are assuming a familiarity with the GUI which not all users may have.

Comment: @tripleee Do you really think that somebody that is looking up something on superuser or asking a cogent question, is not familiar with the flashing cursor indicating focus.  The guy asking this is familiar with ctrl-v as paste,  it'd be a bit absurd if he didn't know about a flashing cursor. But if he didn't or you thought he didn't then you could always tell him or ask him if he knows or point to a link that explains it. It's quite a crucial thing to know and if you seriously thought he might not know then it'd be worth mentioning. Though I think we can assume a 'superuser' knows about that.

Comment: this answer is worded much better now

Comment: It's not just the OP, it's future visitors too, many of whom lack the sophistication to even ask for clarification using correct or at least understandable terminology.

Comment: @barlop not even just sophistication, also stack exchange reputation. This was something I wondered how to do long before I had a stack exchange account, and just remembered to ask it when it came up again; I imagine many people without accounts and with less understanding of the lingo will read it as well.

Comment: @ProQ You're misunderstanding the conversation. I am not saying your question is one that any superuser would know how to do. Your question is a good question.   I (in reference to the original wording of this answer), said that any super user would know that when a textbox has a flashing cursor then it has focus.   Triplee wrote that to say such a thing assumes a familiarity with the GUI that not all users may have.